# Codeblocks variable highlighting... what's happened?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

**Background**:
I'm a big fan of using Codeblocks to do C++. I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and installed Codeblocks via the Ubuntu Software Centre.

**My Problem:** All is going great, apart from one minor thing which is missing. When I double click on a variable, other instances of that variable *used to* be highlighted too. This was an extremely useful way I debugged my programs. But it isn't here on the new version for some reason.

I would like the feature shown in the screenshot below to be set. Where is the option?

[image]

Please can someone help me out, maybe there's an option I'm missing?

Comment: Perhaps this can help you : http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=11290.0

Comment: in particular -- I would like to know how to turn the following feature back on:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/2BEap.png

Comment: Jamey D -- unfortunately I cannot find what I am looking for on that link. Please let me know if you have any other suggestions

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Install the contrib plugins for Code::Blocks IDE (codeblocks-contrib) to enable occurrences highlighting in Code::Blocks.

```
sudo apt install codeblocks-contrib
```

In Code::Blocks select *Settings* -> *Editor* -> *Occurrences Highlighting* (scroll down in the pane on the left side to find it) and then put a check mark in the three checkboxes under *Highlight occurrences of selection* as shown in the below screenshot.

The three checkboxes to select are:

1. Highlight occurrences
2. Case sensitive
3. Whole words only

Then click the **OK** button to apply the changed settings. You can also put a check mark to the left of the two settings under *Permanently highlighted occurrences* in order to apply these settings.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

karel -- Thank you very much for your answer. I believe this will be the thing which will solve most people's question.

For completion, I would like to document my different answer (for other forum users).

I simply had to install the optional extras on the Ubuntu software centre alongside the Codeblocks installation. The menu "occurence highlighting" did not appear without doing this.

Best wishes.